# ADC Maps Grid to Lat/Long Coords Conversion

Tags: convert

While the ADC site apparently has a paid conversion function, it's interactive, and I'm looking for some way to do so on a batch basis, possibly with an API.  Any hope?

Comment: Is [this](http://www.myadcmaps.com/tour.aspx) the converter you are referencing?

Comment: Nope.  That converts between their own old grid system and their own new grid system.  (See my subject line.)